# PHP SQL Statement not inner joining

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm having issues with my SQL statement. I have these tables and columns:

`hotels: id, name, stars, check_in, check_out, location_id, style_id`

`locations: id, location`

`styles: id,name`

When i try and run the sql to inner join these tables together it doesnt work propely, the hotels info gets fetched but theres no location or styles added:
This is the function:

```
$stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare('SELECT
                 hotels.id,
                 hotels.name AS hotel_name,
                 hotels.stars,
                 hotels.check_in,
                 hotels.check_out,
                 hotels.location_id,
                 hotels.style_id
                 FROM hotels
                 INNER JOIN locations ON hotels.location_id = locations.id
                 INNER JOIN styles ON hotels.style_id = styles.id
                 ;');
```

Am i doing anything wrong?
thanks

Comment: You only select columns from `hotels`, but nothing from the other 2 tables? For the last 2 select columns, you probably meant to select `locations.location, styles.name` instead to get that info?

Comment: when i am var dumping the info i also should get the location and style from the two tables that im joining but im not getting anything from them tables

Comment: Then ensure there are matching id's in the tables, or there won't be any matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not selecting columns from the other 2 tables, that's why you don't get the info. You should do something like:

```
$stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare('SELECT
                 hotels.id,
                 hotels.name AS hotel_name,
                 hotels.stars,
                 hotels.check_in,
                 hotels.check_out,
                 hotels.location_id,
                 hotels.style_id,
                 locations.location,
                 styles.name as style_name
                 FROM hotels
                 INNER JOIN locations ON hotels.location_id = locations.id
                 INNER JOIN styles ON hotels.style_id = styles.id
                 ;');
```